# In XSLT, can you use XPath on dynamically created elements?

Tags: php, xslt, xpath

Would you expect this to work or not? (it seems you can't use XPath on dynamically created elements, perhaps because they're not in the 'behind the scenes' magic used to make XPath perform well)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:variable name="data">
      <fu><bar>Test</bar></fu>
    </xsl:variable>

    Value: <xsl:value-of select="$data/fu/bar" />

  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I get an error in the XSLT processors that I've tried, e.g. "invalid type" when using PHP5; removing the "$" from before "data" will make the error go away, but obviously not do what is desired, as it will try to match data/fu/bar from the XML document that the XSLT is being ran against.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't any easy answers to this, but "the way" to do this is with the the node-set() function.  But it's not technically part of XSLT 1.0 and therefore isn't necessarily supported by all transformation engines.  See this link for more info: http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/07/16/nodeset.html

Basically, $data is a string, not a tree, so you need a special function to convert it into a tree.  That is why you are getting "invalid type" - a data type mismatch.

Comment: Thanks - Once again, if I was only was using XSLT 2.0! :)

Comment: It is possible to apply an XPath to the variable in XSLT 1.0 without using node-set() exetension functions.  Use `document('')` to reference the XSLT itself.  I posted an answer with an example.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`document()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#function-document) function with an empty string value in order to reference the root node of the stylesheet from where the function call was made. Then, use XPath to select what you want.

So, rather than reference the `$data` variable in the select, use the following XPath:

```
document('')/xsl:stylesheet/xsl:template[@match='/']/xsl:variable[@name='data']/fu/bar
```

Applied to your XSLT:

```
  <xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:variable name="data">
      <fu><bar>Test</bar></fu>
    </xsl:variable>

    Value: <xsl:value-of 
         select="document('')/xsl:stylesheet
                   /xsl:template[@match='/']/xsl:variable[@name='data']/fu/bar" />

  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: A stylesheet parsing itself!  ZOMG! +1  Isn't that illegal in Alabama though?

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work fine in XSLT 2.0 but not in XSLT 1.0. In XSLT 1.0 you aren't allowed to use path expressions to navigate into a result-tree-fragment; the usual work-around is the exslt:node-set() extension function.